# Adding tags to images in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, tags

How can I add support for adding tags to images the same way you can add tags to posts in Wordpress?

I know I can do this by installing a plugin such as the Shiba media library plugin, but that adds a whole lot more than I need. I just need to be able to add tags, no more.

Answer (score 13):

see this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/applying-categories-tags-and-custom-taxonomies-to-media-attachments--wp-32319 that explains it all very well.

To use the same tags as your posts you'll just need to add those lines to your functions.php file:

```
    function wptp_add_tags_to_attachments() {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
    }
    add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

After adding those, the tags box will start showing up on your media library items.

The article also describes how to create custom taxonomy (a separate set of tags / categories) but that's probably not required for what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to add media tags :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-media-tags/

Or you can dig this solution :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/adding-category-tag-taxonomy-support-to-images-media

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution.

1. Download the Shiba Media Library plugin at:
   http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/media-library-plus-plugin
2. Install it.
3. Download the Admin Menu Editor plugin at:
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/
4. install it.
5. With the Admin Menu Editor, hide the gallery menu item (added by the Shiba plugin).

Now I can tag images via the ordinary media library :)